# Ocaml Error: Answer error (please help fix)

Tags: ocaml

I have been stuck with this for more than an hour. So the test bench is at the bottom, and the answer is supposed to show 120 but I keep getting 20. I believe it only does 5 * 4 not the rest of 3 2 and 1.
What is the problem??

I tried to fix all the other ones but they seem correct. is it a calculation error? is it WHILE problem?

```
type exp =
  | NUM of int | TRUE | FALSE | UNIT
  | VAR of id
  | ADD of exp * exp
  | SUB of exp * exp
  | MUL of exp * exp
  | DIV of exp * exp
  | EQUAL of exp * exp
  | LESS of exp * exp
  | NOT of exp
  | SEQ of exp * exp                 (* sequence *)
  | IF of exp * exp * exp            (* if-then-else *)
  | WHILE of exp * exp               (* while loop *)
  | LETV of id * exp * exp           (* variable binding *)
  | LETF of id * id list * exp * exp (* procedure binding *)
  | CALLV of id * exp list           (* call by value *)
  | CALLR of id * id list            (* call by referenece *)
  | RECORD of (id * exp) list        (* record construction *)
  | FIELD of exp * id                (* access record field *)
  | ASSIGN of id * exp               (* assgin to variable *)
  | ASSIGNF of exp * id * exp        (* assign to record field *)
  | WRITE of exp
and id = string

type loc = int
type value =
| Num of int
| Bool of bool
| Unit
| Record of record 
and record = (id * loc) list
type memory = (loc * value) list
type env = binding list
and binding = LocBind of id * loc | ProcBind of id * proc
and proc = id list * exp * env

(********************************)
(*     Handling environment     *)
(********************************)

let rec lookup_loc_env : id -> env -> loc
= fun x env ->
  match env with
  | [] -> raise(Failure ("Variable "^x^" is not included in environment"))
  | hd::tl ->
    begin match hd with
    | LocBind (id,l) -> if(x=id) then l else lookup_loc_env x tl
    | ProcBind _ -> lookup_loc_env x tl
    end

let rec lookup_proc_env : id -> env -> proc
= fun x env ->
  match env with
  | [] -> raise(Failure ("Variable "^x^" is not included in environment"))
  | hd::tl ->
    begin match hd with
    | LocBind _ -> lookup_proc_env x tl
    | ProcBind (id,binding) -> if (x=id) then binding else lookup_proc_env x tl
    end

let extend_env : binding -> env -> env
= fun e env -> e::env

let empty_env = []`enter code here`
(***************************)
(*     Handling memory     *)
(***************************)

let rec lookup_mem : loc -> memory -> value
= fun l mem ->
  match mem with
  | [] -> raise(Failure ("location "^(string_of_int l)^" is not included in memory"))
  | (loc,v)::tl -> if(l=loc) then v else lookup_mem l tl

let extend_mem : (loc * value) -> memory -> memory
= fun (l,v) mem -> (l,v)::mem

let empty_mem = []

(***************************)
(*     Handling record     *)
(***************************)

let rec lookup_record : id -> record -> loc
= fun id record -> 
  match record with
    | [] -> raise(Failure ("field "^ id ^" is not included in record"))
    | (x,l)::tl -> if(id=x) then l else lookup_record id tl


let extend_record : (id * loc) -> record -> record
= fun (x,l) record -> (x,l)::record

let empty_record = []

(***************************)

let counter = ref 0
let new_location () = counter:=!counter+1;!counter

exception NotImplemented
exception UndefinedSemantics

let rec list_fold2 : ('a -> 'b -> 'c -> 'c)-> 'a list -> 'b list -> 'c -> 'c
= fun func l1 l2 acc ->
  match (l1,l2) with
  | ([],[]) -> acc
  | (hd1::tl1,hd2::tl2) -> list_fold2 func tl1 tl2 (func hd1 hd2 acc)
  | _ -> raise (Failure "two lists have different length")

let rec list_fold : ('a -> 'b -> 'b) -> 'a list -> 'b -> 'b
= fun func l acc ->
  match l with
  | [] -> acc
  | hd::tl -> list_fold func tl (func hd acc)

let value2str : value -> string
= fun v ->
  match v with
  | Num n -> string_of_int n
  | Bool b -> string_of_bool b
  | Unit -> "unit"
  | Record _ -> "record" 

let rec eval_aop : env -> memory -> exp -> exp -> (int -> int -> int) -> (value * memory)
= fun env mem e1 e2 op ->
  let (v1,mem1) = eval env mem e1 in
  let (v2,mem2) = eval env mem1 e2 in
  match (v1,v2) with
  | (Num n1, Num n2) -> (Num (op n1 n2), mem2)
  | _ -> raise (Failure "arithmetic operation type error")

and eval : env -> memory -> exp -> (value * memory) 
=fun env mem e -> 
   match e with
  | NUM n -> (Num n, mem) 
  | TRUE -> (Bool true, mem)
  | FALSE -> (Bool false, mem)
  | UNIT -> (Unit, mem)
  | VAR x -> ((lookup_mem (lookup_loc_env x env) mem ), mem )
  | ADD (e1, e2) -> eval_aop env mem e1 e2 (+) 
  | SUB (e1, e2) -> eval_aop env mem e1 e2 (-)
  | MUL (e1, e2) -> eval_aop env mem e1 e2 ( * )
  | DIV (e1, e2) -> eval_aop env mem e1 e2 (/)
  |EQUAL (e1, e2) ->
      let (v1, mem1) = eval env mem e1 in
      let (v2, mem2) = eval env mem1 e2 in
        if v1 = v2 then (Bool true, mem2) else (Bool false, mem2)
  |LESS (e1, e2) -> 
      let (v1, mem1) = eval env mem e1 in
      let (v2, mem2) = eval env mem1 e2 in
      begin match (v1, v2) with 
        | (Num n1, Num n2) -> 
        if Num n1 < Num n2 then (Bool true, mem2) else (Bool false, mem2)
        | _ -> raise (UndefinedSemantics)
        end
        
  |NOT (e1) ->
    let (b, mem1) = eval env mem e1 in
      if b = b then (Bool false,mem1) else (Bool true,mem1)
  |SEQ (e1, e2) ->
    let (v1, mem1) = eval env mem e1 in 
    let (v2, mem2) = eval env mem1 e2 in
        (v2,mem2)
  |IF (e1,e2,e3) -> 
    (match (eval env mem e1) with 
      | (Bool true, mem1) -> eval env mem1 e1
      | (Bool false, mem1) -> eval env mem1 e2
      | _ -> raise (UndefinedSemantics) )
  |WHILE (e1,e2) ->
   begin match (eval env mem e1) with
      | (Bool true, mem1) ->
          let (v1, mem2) = eval env mem1 e2 in
            eval env mem2 e2
      | (Bool false, mem1) -> (Unit, mem1)
      | _ -> raise (UndefinedSemantics) 
      
      end
  |LETV (x,e1,e2) ->
    let (v1, mem1) = eval env mem e1 in
    let a = LocBind (x, (new_location()) ) in 
    let (v2,mem2) = eval (extend_env a env) (extend_mem ((lookup_loc_env x)(extend_env a env), v1) mem1 )e2 in
    (v2,mem2)
    
  | ASSIGN (x,e1) ->
    let (v1, mem1) = eval env mem e1 in 
    (v1, extend_mem ((lookup_loc_env x env) , (v1) ) mem1) 
    
  | WRITE e -> 
    let (v1,mem1) = eval env mem e in
    let _ = print_endline(value2str v1) in
    (v1,mem1)
  
  
 | _ -> raise NotImplemented
;;
      
    
    

let runb : exp -> value 
=fun exp -> let (v, _) = eval empty_env empty_mem exp in v;;



let test = LETV ("ret", NUM 1,
LETV ("n", NUM 5,
SEQ (
WHILE (LESS (NUM 0, VAR "n"),
SEQ (
ASSIGN ("ret", MUL (VAR "ret", VAR "n")),
ASSIGN ("n", SUB (VAR "n", NUM 1))
)
),
VAR "ret")))
;;

runb test;;
```

Comment: Please do NOT vandalize the question. Questions regarding debugging should include a [mcve], also _after_ it's been answered. When submitting a question you license your code to SO under a CC-BY-SA license and cannot revoke that later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When evaluating `WHILE` you need to make sure the inner expression is evaluated as a `WHILE`. But you are evaluating it just as itself. In other words, the recursive call to `eval` should be passing `e` but you are just passing `e2`.

As a result you're just getting two evaluations of the loop, which gives 20.

So it seems to me.